# Does anyone know how to convert binary data stored into a database back into an image?

Tags: php, image, binary

A database has stored an image as binary. I'm looking to convert it back to a JPEG in PHP. Does anyone know how this might be accomplished?

I'm aware this might be something that I can find through Google but I have not yet tracked down an answer and thought it would be best to hedge my bets and ask a question here.

If I find out before I get a response, I will post the solution here.

Comment: Do you mean be able to manipulate it with PHP?  Otherwise, it's already a JPEG, if you save it with `fopen` specifying the binary flag, it should render properly.

Comment: Sounds like it's just a matter of doing a database request and `file_put_contents()` to send the data back into a file. Or is there some stumbling stone you didn't mention? What does "binary" mean for you?

Comment: "Binary" is meaningless. Any format is binary.

Comment: The deal was that the database creators stored the image as "binary" info in the database rather than point to a spot on the server.  Regarding this being meaningless, I'm not sure what other term I would use.  I have read the term "blob" when searching online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply select the data from the database and put it in the variable $image_data_from_database

Save to file:

```
<?php
    file_put_contents("image.jpg", $image_data_from_database);
?>
```

or display the image in-place:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo $image_data_from_database;
?>
```